# React Native Public Key Pinning with HEROKU

Tags: react-native, security, ssl, heroku, sslpinning

I read all kind of posts and articles about ssl pinning in react native.
However all of those are about a privately owned domain for which we generate the certificate.

But if my API is hosted on Heroku, how can I manage SSL pinning?

Ideally, I would like to pin on hashed public key so it's easier to manage the rotation without having to release a new version.
But I have no clue how to deal with this with Heroku, with my api being hosted at myapp.herokyapp.com for example.

Also, if I suddenly add SSL pinning for my heroku, will it affect all my previous users in the current mobile version that are currently hitting on this same API?
I wouldn't want existing users to have all their requests failing.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hey, How far have you gone about this issue, can we sync and look at in-depth, I am also trying to implement SSL pining

Comment: Unfortunately I had to abandon it considering how complex it was on an existing infrastructure.
I went to add an additional layer of security to my API through captcha instead.

Comment: Hello, okay thanks for the reply, I am actually using network security configuration for android and trust kit for ios, just in case you would like to use it.